# How are the bits allocated?

Tags: opencv

In OpenCV, the type of the elements in a `cv::Mat` object could be for instance `CV_32FC1`, `CV_32FC3` which represent 32-bit floating point with one channel and 32-bit floating point with three channels, respectively.

The `CV_32FC3` type can be used to represent color images which have blue, green and red channels plus an alpha channel used to represent transparency, with each channel getting 8 bits.

I'm wondering how the bits being allocated in `CV_32FC1` type, when there's only one channel?

Answer (score 0):

`32F` means `float`. The number after the `C` is the number of channels. So `CV_32FC3` means 3 `float`s per pixel, while `CV_32FC1` is one float only. What these floats mean is up to you and not explicitly stored in the `Mat`.

The float is stored in memory as it would in your regular C program (typically in little endian).

A classical BGR image (default channel ordering in OpenCV) would be a `CV_8UC3`: 8 bit unsigned integer per channel in three channels.